# Property 'item' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { name: string; href: string; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm learning TypeScript to use in a personal React project. I'm having difficulty resolving this error:

```
ERROR in src/components/navigation/Navigation.tsx:16:27
TS2322: Type '{ item: { name: string; href: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { name: string; href: string; }'.
  Property 'item' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { name: string; href: string; }'.
    14 |         <Navbar.Brand>{data.navbar.navBrand}</Navbar.Brand>
    15 |         { data.navbar.navItems.forEach(navItem => {
  > 16 |           <NavigationItem item={navItem} />
       |                           ^^^^
    17 |         })}
    18 |       </Container>
    19 |     </Navbar>
```

What I have is the following:

```
// Navigation.tsx
// Bootstrap imports
import { Container, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';

// Component imports
import NavigationItem from './NavigationItem';

// Import data
import data from '../../data/data.json';

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar bg='light'>
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand>{data.navbar.navBrand}</Navbar.Brand>
        { data.navbar.navItems.forEach(navItem => {
          <NavigationItem item={navItem} />
        })}
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

```
// NavigationItem.tsx
const NavigationItem = (props: {name: string, href: string }): JSX.Element => {
  return <a href={props.href}>{props.name}</a>;
};

export default NavigationItem;
```

```
// data.json
{
  "navbar": {
    "navBrand": "My Name",
    "navItems": [
      {
        "name": "Bio",
        "href": "#bio"
      },
      {
        "name": "Projects",
        "href": "#projects"
      },
      {
        "name": "Articles",
        "href": "#articles"
      },
      {
        "name": "Resume",
        "href": "#resume"
      },
      {
        "name": "Contact",
        "href": "#contact"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My expectation is that this should work because `<NavigationItem />` is receiving an object (`navItem`) and has the necessary type declaration for `props` (`props: {name: string, href: string }`).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `NavigationItem.tsx`, you are expecting a props which is having only `name` and `href`

But, when you are using `NavigationItem.tsx` in `Navigation.tsx`, you are passing it in the attribute named `item`. So, edit your `NavigationItem.tsx`

```
const NavigationItem = (props: {item:{name: string, href: string }}): JSX.Element => {
 return <a href={props.item.href}>{props.item.name}</a>;
};

export default NavigationItem;
```

Or, edit your `NavigationItem` in `Navigation.tsx` like this

```
<NavigationItem {...navItem} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting an object as:

```
{ name: string; href: string; }
```

and passing as:

```
{ item: { name: string; href: string; }; }
```

**1)** Both of their types are different, so what you can do is:

```
<NavigationItem item={navItem} />
```

and expect as:

```
interface IItem {     // IItemp type contains name and href
    name: string,
    href: string
}

interface INavigationItemProps {
    item: IItem      // Expecting an item of type IItem
}

// NavigationItem.tsx
const NavigationItem = (props: INavigationItemProps): JSX.Element => {
    return <a href={props.item.name}>{props.item.href}</a>;  // NOTICE
};
```

**2)** You can pass just `name` and `href` as:

```
<NavigationItem { ...item } />
```

and

```
// NavigationItem.tsx
const NavigationItem = (props: { name: string, href: string }): JSX.Element => {
    return <a href={props.href}>{props.name}</a>;
};
```